unable to run playwright test due to a windows app popup
enter image description hereI am new to Playwright. I am trying to run my playwright test in windows 10 machine from commandline . I am unable to run my test due to a app selection pop up. Here is an image.
Any one else had the same problem? please provide a solution

What command did you run? You should be running npx playwright test. Make sure node/npm/npx are installed.
